# Print preview and Printer-friendly version look different

Tags: theming

I am using a Print module with a bartik subtheme. I am trying to override the print module styles by using my theme's print.css file. Is this correc tway of doing this?

Both the print preview and preview via the printer-friendly version generated by the print module look different...

How would I go about overriding the print module styles?

This is how the print stylesheet is being called in my theme:
stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css

Comment: What is different about them?  Are you using http://drupal.org/project/print?

Comment: That's the one. The sections that are displaying/not displaying are different @MPD

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean when you say _print preview_ and _preview_. Can you add the screenshots (and/or urls) as it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate stylesheets.

The 'preview' stylesheet needs to be configured in the CMS. You just enter into a field something like 'print.css' and create that file in your theme folder. This is nothing different than a typical stylesheet you would use anywhere else on the site.

The actual 'print' stylesheet (what you get when you press the print button) that you have declared in your .info file will style the resulting print.

Comment: Thanks for that @AlexGill

When I edit my print.css the changes are reflected in print preview but not when I select the print button...

Comment: The answer from @Alex Gill is awesome!! really helpful for me. Thanks for sharing with us. Following links also helped me to complete my task. http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/83e5fed0-9db4-4b35-b34b-cca8de153655/?Print%20and%20Print%20Preview%20separately%20using%20HTML%20CSS%20and%20JavaScript http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/503415/Print-Div-Content-Using-JavaScript